# Matlab: Turning try/catch on and off for debugging

Tags: matlab, debugging, if-statement, try-catch

I am using a try-catch statement for a lengthy calcuation similar to the following:

```
for i=1:1000
    try 
        %do a lot of stuff
    catch me
        sendmail('foo@bar.bz', 'Error in Matlab', parse_to_string(me));
    end
end
```

When I am writing on my code I do not want to jump in the catch statement because I like Matlabs `dbstop if error` feature. 
I know it is possible to use `dbstop if all error` in order to avoid jumping in the catch statement (I found that here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/102907 .)

But the problem is that Matlab has a lot of inbuilt functions which throw errors which are caught and handled by other inbuilt functions. I only want to stop at errors caused by me.

My approach would be to use some statement similar to

```
global debugging; % set from outside my function as global variable
for i=1:1000
    if  ~debugging 
        try 
    end

        %do a lot of stuff

    if  ~debugging
        catch me
            sendmail('foo@bar.bz', 'Error in Matlab', parse_to_string(me));
        end
    end 
end
```

This does not work because Matlab doesn't see that try and  catch belong to each other.

Are there any better approaches to handle `try/catch` statements when debugging? I have been commenting in and out the `try/catch`, but that is pretty annoying and cumbersome.

Comment: sorry, have been writing on it and didn't realize I had already sent the first part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

The solution that you are looking for is `dbstop if caught error`.

Before I found that, debugging code with `try catch` blocks always drove me crazy.

Comment: It didn't work to me. It seems to have the same issue OP mentioned with `dbstop if all error`: it stops at harmless Matlab exceptions---like accessing an invalid field instead of testing if it exists.

Comment: @giusti Please avoid using comments to ask questions. If you have something that does not get resolved by using `dbstop if caught error` (so not `all` error), please create a new question including a minimum reproducible example. Of course you may refer to this question, but your question should be readable on its own.

Comment: I didn't post a question.

Comment: @giusti You are right, most 'it doesn't work' comments are implicit questions, but of course they do not need to be. -- Note that it may actually be interesting to ask a question about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i=1:1000
    try 
        %do a lot of stuff
    catch me
        if ~debugging
             sendmail('foo@bar.bz', 'Error in Matlab', parse_to_string(me));
        else
             rethrow(me)
        end
    end
end
```

This code should match your requirements.

Comment: It does do what I want it to do at the small tradeoff that I dont stop where the error originally occurs (as it would when I just use `dbstop if error`). But that one click that I have to perform to have the debug stack at the right place is quite ok.

Comment: I have been trying this now, and it does not match my requirements: When Stopped at dbstop if error, I do not have any information about what the workspaces of the subfunctions contain, only about the place where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbclear.html#:~:text=dbclear%20all%20removes%20all%20breakpoints,The%20in%20keyword%20is%20optional.), `dbclear all` removes all breakpoints in all MATLAB® code files, and all breakpoints set for errors, caught errors, caught error identifiers, warnings, warning identifiers, and naninf.

If you need to remove all the breakpoints in a certain file you can use `dbclear in mFilePath` and you can always use `dbstatus` to check the current setup.

And as @dennis-jaheruddin mentioned, `dbstop if caught error` could be used for run-time error that occurs within the try portion of a try/catch block. If you want to clear a breakpoint set for a specific error, then specify the message id.